# What is the meaning of できる in 「影{かげ}がどこにできる」?

Tags: verbs

The context is the following:

> 日時計{ひどけい}は太陽{たいよう}の位置{いち}が変{か}わるのを利用{りよう}して、影{かげ}がどこにできるかで時間{じかん}が分{わ}かる時計{とけい}です。

My best guess is that できる takes the meaning of growing, as the place where the shadow extends/grows to, but I'm not completely sure of it. My attempt at a translation would be "The sundial utilizes the change in position of the sun and tells the time by the place where (its) shadow extends to."

*Is my assumption and translation correct?*

Comment: @SadaharuWakisaka, please try to avoid answering questions in the comment section. [Comments are not for answers](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/q/593/9831). See also [here](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: You again. I thought this question can not be answered or duplicated of some others. And I do know he wanted some hints. I did not intend to answer this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try thinking of this 〜ができる more along the lines of "〜 didn't used to exist, but now it does". This is closest to [#1 here](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E5%87%BA%E6%9D%A5%E3%82%8B_%28%E3%81%A7%E3%81%8D%E3%82%8B%29/), but can be applied in a general sense to many of the other definitions given.

Ex)

彼女ができた。→ A girlfriend didn't used to exist, but now she does. → (Contextually defined person) got a girlfriend.

顎に大量のニキビができて治らない。→ On (contextually defined person's) chin many zits that weren't there before are now there, and they won't heal. → (Contextually defined person) got a bunch of zits on their chin and they won't go away.

影がどこにできるかで時間が分かる。 → Based on where a/the shadow goes from not existing to existing, the time is understood. → The time is understood based on where a/the shadow falls.